# How to make a picture rounded

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple upload. Where the user can upload his profile. The problem is, right now it is a square, and I just want to make it rounded. I have this so far.

CSS:

```
.pic {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%; 
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The actual circle behind it is rounded, but when the user inserts his profile pic it is square and not rounded, so any help would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Round the corners of the picture instead of the container div.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i tried but it did not worl, think i did it wrong, so maybe someone can show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my years of experience I would recommend doing it with the following:

.pic > img

Thats is how it is done in the olden days my friend!

Answer (score 2):

**Four ways to do it**:

**1**- an image with `border-radius: 50%;`

**2**- a container with `border-radius: 50%;` and an image as background

**3**- a container with `border-radius: 50%;` and an image inside

**4**- an image with a SVG circle `clip-path` (current method not working on IE and Firefox - today 2016)

```css
body {
  background: honeydew;  
}

#pic {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#imgcontainer {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#pic2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#pic3 {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}

span {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<span>1.<img id=pic src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg"></span><span>2.<div id=imgcontainer></div></span><span>3.<div id=container><img id=pic2 src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg"></div></span><span>4.<img id=pic3 src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg"></span>
```

Comment: This is great is well but the answer above did it in a line which was very good, but thank u those for the help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it will work with custom uploads and php but this is the code to round an image

```css
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-circle" src="http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

1)  Apply a class to your `<img />` tag:

```
<img class="UserProfile" width='100%' height='100%' src='Image/userImages/profile.png' alt='Default Profile Pic'>
```

2)  Create your CSS for that class, with `border-radius: 50%`:

```
.UserProfile
{
  height:60%;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

---

I make a CodePen of it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyoEwz.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  background: honeydew;  
}

#pic {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#imgcontainer {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#pic2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#pic3 {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}

span {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<span>1.<img id="pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg"></span><span>2.<div id="imgcontainer"></div></span><span>3.<div id="container"><img id="pic2" src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg"></div></span><span>4.<img id="pic3" src="http://i.imgur.com/YwbFAEg.jpg"></span>
```